# Is there any way to get portable apps to register in the Explorer context menu?

Tags: 7-zip, portable-apps

I am using more and more [portable apps](http://portableapps.com) which make switching from computer to computer much easier.

However for programs such as 7zip which makes sense really only if it is a choice in the context menu in Explorer, **is there a way to get this programs to register themselves in the Explorer context menu** even though they are portable apps?

Comment: Portable apps don't have a registry entry, which is required to use the context menu I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up the Options in 7-Zip you could potentially enable the context menu there, which may work for what you need.  The program should be intelligent enough to set up Explorer properly.

```
7-Zip -> Tools -> Options
```

Under the `7-Zip` tab you can enable the context menu but selecting `Integrate 7-Zip to shell contect menu`

I would go through these options to disable the context menu before you remove the portable disk as I do not know how well Explorer would handle the context handler not being present without the USB device plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [registry hack for Notepad++](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/). I suppose you could modify it to work with 7-zip instead. Note that the script must be run with administrator privilege, and that you might need to restart the explorer.exe process after uninstalling.